# Search string not passing to php on bootstrap autosuggest

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, typeahead

I am trying to pass a search parameter to a PHP script for a bootstrap autosuggest - but the parameter does not come through. I have taken sample code and trying to adjust it but cant get it right

Here is the div:

```
<div class="autosuggest" data-minLength="1" data-queryURL="../../php/autos_project.php?limit=10&qstring=">
    <input id="ddproject" placeholder="Project:" class="form-control typeahead" style="width: 100%;">
</div>
```

Trying to echo `qstring` in PHP:

```
echo "qstring is " . $_REQUEST['qstring'];
```

But get `qstring` is `%QUERY`

I require the `qstring` to be set to the value the user types in.

Comment: Here is the div

Comment: <div class="autosuggest" data-minLength="1" data-queryURL="../../php/autos_project.php?limit=10&qstring=">
 <input id="ddproject" placeholder="Project:" class="form-control typeahead" style="width: 100%;">
</div>